# Sound playing notification on IPhone

Tags: iphone, audio, notifications

When playing sound on IPhone using AVAudioPlyer,
How to be notified when reaches certain time during the playing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is delegate method when AVAudioPlayer is finished successfully,

```
- (void)audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying:(AVAudioPlayer *)player successfully:(BOOL)flag;
```

If you want to notify user when AVAudioPlayer reaches certain time, you can implement NSTimer using following method.

```
+ (NSTimer *)scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:(NSTimeInterval)ti target:(id)aTarget selector:(SEL)aSelector userInfo:(id)userInfo repeats:(BOOL)yesOrNo;
```